# What is the order in which values are returned by Values() step

Tags: gremlin

Is there a well-defined order in the response we get from the Values() step?
g.V().values()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gremlin does not do anything to guarantee order of graph elements (vertices, edges, properties). Gremlin relies on the underlying graph database to determine the the order of things so you should look to your implementation to determine that. If you want to ensure an order with Gremlin, then you need to use the `order()` step.